# Rails Routes Mappings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm a rails newbie, and I have a controller called `resource_links` that I've mapped to `resources`:

```
resources :resources, :as => :resource_links, :controller => :resource_links
```

And this works (basically `/resources` works as `/resource_links`). However, trying to go to `/resources/tags` does not work. To get around this, I added more mappings as:

```
  match 'resource_links/tag/:tag(.:format)' => 'resource_links#tag', :via => :get, :as => 'resource_links_tagged', :constraints => {:tag => /.*/}
  match 'resource_links/tags' => 'resource_links#tags', :via => :get, :as => 'resource_links_tags'
```

Is there any way I can get `/resources/tags` to be mapped to `/resource_links/tag`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try :

```
  match 'resource/tag/:tag(.:format)' => 'resource_links#tag', :via => :get, :as => 'resource_links_tagged'
  match 'resource/tags' => 'resource_links#tags', :via => :get, :as => 'resource_links_tags'
```

OR USE LIKE (more readable) :

```
  match 'resource/tag/:tag(.:format)', :controller => 'resource_links', :action => 'tag', :via => :get, :as => 'resource_links_tagged'
  match 'resource/tags', :controller => 'resource_links', :action => 'tags', :via => :get, :as => 'resource_links_tags'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend default restful routes this way

```
resources :resources, :as => :resource_links, :controller => :resource_links do
  collection do
    get :tags
    get 'tag/:tag', :action => :tag, :as => :tagged
  end
end
```

Next, look at output of `rake routes` to check how route helpers named.

```
  tags_resource_links GET    /resources/tags(.:format)     resource_links#tags
tagged_resource_links GET    /resources/tag/:tag(.:format) resource_links#tag
       resource_links GET    /resources(.:format)          resource_links#index
                      POST   /resources(.:format)          resource_links#create
    new_resource_link GET    /resources/new(.:format)      resource_links#new
   edit_resource_link GET    /resources/:id/edit(.:format) resource_links#edit
        resource_link GET    /resources/:id(.:format)      resource_links#show
                      PUT    /resources/:id(.:format)      resource_links#update
                      DELETE /resources/:id(.:format)      resource_links#destroy
```